# rosmake gmapping stack

Tags: slam, navigation, rosmake, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i want to build the gmapping package and ROS_nobuild is stopping me to do that i tried
with rosmake -u but its not working sating that permission denied.

Actually i want to make some changes in gmapping and also the wrapper class slam_gmapping.cpp

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31109/rosmake-gmapping-stack/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2012-04-03**:
Have you tried changing the owner of the gmapping package to your username? As in sudo chown zeeq:zeeq -r gmapping ?

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-04-04**:
thanks PKG it helped .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried changing the owner of the gmapping package to your username? As in sudo chown zeeq:zeeq -r gmapping ?
PKG (Apr 3 '12)edit
thanks PKG it helped .....
Zee-Q (Apr 4 '12)edit

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1